# How does d3's path.bounds work?

Tags: d3.js, topojson, datamaps

I have a file `world.topo.json` in TopoJson format which I took from https://datamaps.github.io/ and use it in a **d3** geo chart (using `merchant` projection).

It works well, but I find quite odd why, when I call `path.bounds(<TopoJson File Content>.objects.world.feature)` and get these values:

```
[
    [-25.272818452358365, -114.9648719971861],
    [917.2049776245796, 507.5180814546301]
]
```

So, why is the botom/left corner pointing to -25 and -114? Shouldn't them be either `0,0` or `-917, -507` instead?

**Update:** I have a zoom behavior object bound to my d3 chart, **which works for me exactly as expected**. So, I've written a `console.log` for every zoom/drag even like below:

```
const topojson = <response of an ajax request>;
const bounds = path.bounds(topojson.objects.world.feature);
console.log(translate, JSON.stringify(path.bounds(feature))); // XXX
```

So, every single time zoom/drag even is called, this is the type of output I get:

```
[25, 120] "[[-25.272818452358365,-114.9648719971861],[917.2049776245796,507.5180814546301]]"
```

The first array being the current **translate** and the second being the bounds.

But, when I drag/pan or zoom, here is the output:

```
[0.021599999999999998, 0.10368] "[[-25.272818452358365,-114.9648719971861],[917.2049776245796,507.5180814546301]]"
[24.88185889212827, 119.4329226822157] "[[-25.272818452358365,-114.9648719971861],[917.2049776245796,507.5180814546301]]"
[25, 120] "[[-25.272818452358365,-114.9648719971861],[917.2049776245796,507.5180814546301]]"
[25, 120] "[[-25.272818452358365,-114.9648719971861],[917.2049776245796,507.5180814546301]]"
[-15, 119] "[[-25.272818452358365,-114.9648719971861],[917.2049776245796,507.5180814546301]]"
[-27, 117] "[[-25.272818452358365,-114.9648719971861],[917.2049776245796,507.5180814546301]]"
[-27.32184332502962, 117.03468139278337] "[[-25.272818452358365,-114.9648719971861],[917.2049776245796,507.5180814546301]]"
[-125.83796642848066, 127.65064293410353] "[[-25.272818452358365,-114.9648719971861],[917.2049776245796,507.5180814546301]]"
[-165.15379127139124, 131.88726199045166] "[[-25.272818452358365,-114.9648719971861],[917.2049776245796,507.5180814546301]]"
[-173.98081187505056, 132.83844955550114] "[[-25.272818452358365,-114.9648719971861],[917.2049776245796,507.5180814546301]]"
[-173.98081187505056, 132.83844955550114] "[[-25.272818452358365,-114.9648719971861],[917.2049776245796,507.5180814546301]]"
[-173.4557969093005, 132.7818746669505] "[[-25.272818452358365,-114.9648719971861],[917.2049776245796,507.5180814546301]]"
[-89.06290511198648, 123.68781305086063] "[[-25.272818452358365,-114.9648719971861],[917.2049776245796,507.5180814546301]]"
[-89.06290511198648, 123.68781305086063] "[[-25.272818452358365,-114.9648719971861],[917.2049776245796,507.5180814546301]]"
```

As you can see, although the first argument changes constantly according to zoom and pan events, the bounds remain untouched.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/blob/master/README.md#path_bounds) about `path.bounds(object)`has it covered:

> Returns the projected planar bounding box (typically in pixels) for the specified GeoJSON object. The bounding box is represented by a two-dimensional array: [[x₀, y₀], [x₁, y₁]], where x₀ is the minimum x-coordinate, y₀ is the minimum y-coordinate, x₁ is maximum x-coordinate, and y₁ is the maximum y-coordinate.

So, -25 and -114 are the minimum `x` and `y` values, and refer to the *top left* corner (in the SVG coordinates system), not the bottom left.

Have in mind that `path.bounds` is different from [`geoBounds`](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/blob/master/README.md#geoBounds), which:

> Returns the spherical bounding box for the specified GeoJSON feature. The bounding box is represented by a two-dimensional array: [[left, bottom], [right, top]], where left is the minimum longitude, bottom is the minimum latitude, right is maximum longitude, and top is the maximum latitude.

**How does it work?**

`path.bounds(object)` will use your projection to drawn a "rectangle" around your object and will return an array with the four corners of that rectangle, as described above. Let's see how it works in these demos (this code is not mine):

In this first demo, the map of Japan has an scale of 1000. Check the console to see `path.bounds`.

```js
var topoJsonUrl = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1662536/topojson/japan.topo.json";

var width = 500,
    height = 500,
    scale = 1;

d3.select("body").append("svg")
 .attr("width", width)
 .attr("height", height)
    .append("g").attr("id", "all-g");

var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
  .center([138, 38])
  .scale(1000)
  .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);
    
d3.json(topoJsonUrl, onLoadMap);

function onLoadMap (error, jpn) {
    var path = d3.geo.path()
          .projection(projection);
 var features = topojson.object(jpn, jpn.objects.japan);
  
  var mapJapan = features;
  
 console.log(JSON.stringify(path.bounds(mapJapan)))
  

 d3.select("#all-g")
        .append("g").attr("id", "path-g").selectAll("path")
            .data(features.geometries)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("fill", "#f0f0f0")
            .attr("id", function(d,i){ return "path" + i})
            .attr("stroke", "#999")
            .attr("stroke-width", 0.5/scale)
            .attr("d", path);

}
```

```css
path {
  stroke: black;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v0.min.js"></script>
```

It logs:

```
[[-12.878670523380151,73.71036362631844],[529.0014631418044,535.5463567314675]]
```

Which are [[x0, y0],[x1, y1]] values.

Now the same code, but with a scale of 500:

```js
var topoJsonUrl = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1662536/topojson/japan.topo.json";

var width = 500,
    height = 500,
    scale = 1;

d3.select("body").append("svg")
 .attr("width", width)
 .attr("height", height)
    .append("g").attr("id", "all-g");

var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
  .center([138, 38])
  .scale(500)
  .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);
    
d3.json(topoJsonUrl, onLoadMap);

function onLoadMap (error, jpn) {
    var path = d3.geo.path()
          .projection(projection);
 var features = topojson.object(jpn, jpn.objects.japan);
  
  var mapJapan = features;
  
 console.log(JSON.stringify(path.bounds(mapJapan)))
  

 d3.select("#all-g")
        .append("g").attr("id", "path-g").selectAll("path")
            .data(features.geometries)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("fill", "#f0f0f0")
            .attr("id", function(d,i){ return "path" + i})
            .attr("stroke", "#999")
            .attr("stroke-width", 0.5/scale)
            .attr("d", path);

}
```

```css
path {
  stroke: black;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v0.min.js"></script>
```

It logs different values:

```
[[118.56066473830992,161.85518181315928],[389.5007315709022,392.77317836573377]]
```

Comment: well, ok, I get the bottom/left vs top/left, but my question is why is it **-25/-114** while the other coordinates are **917, 507** ? I mean, how it finds such numbers?For me, the logical values should be either 0,0 or the negative of same values in the other coordinates.

do you follow what I mean? There's no logical relation between -25 and 917, either between -113 and 507. Where are these values produced? I understand they aren't absolute values, that they vary based on the GeoJSON/TopoJSON content, I know that. What I mean is: why -25 while the other is 917?

Comment: I thank your effort, but I think you didn't get my question yet.

Do see that there's no correlation between **-12 and 529**? I mean, shouldn't it be **0 and 541** instead? Or maybe -270.5 and 270.5 in case it had 0,0 in the middle?

I mean **why -12**?

Again: logically speaking, as it outputs the bounds for a rectangle with width 541, **the left should be 0 and the right should 541**. There must be some reason why it returns that number.

I'm aware the scale changes the output, but no matters the scale, it's still hard to understand why **118 and 389**, can you see?

Comment: What you're saying makes no sense. Why should it start at 0? Why should the 0 be in the middle? It returns the **position** of the rectangle in the SVG coordinates system, **relative to the SVG it is in**. Change the translate in the demo above and you'll see the four values changing. I cannot explain it more than I did already. Please have a look at the SVG coordinates system and at D3 projection functions. This is also a good reading: https://www.jasondavies.com/maps/bounds/

Comment: "relative to the SVG it is in" <-- this is the type of answer I was looking for. But it doesn't seem quite much the case. I'm writing more details in the body above so you see the examples why it doesn't feel it. Thank you for the patience.

Comment: @MarinhoBrandão Regarding your edit: `path.bounds(object)` depends on the projection. You're translating the element *after* the projection works.